# How to countifs with multiple not equal<> to variables?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a total number of calls for a sales tracking sheet where if someone scheduled a call yesterday and did not either cancel, reschedule, or no show.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work. I can get it to work if it's just one variable such as <>cancel, but when I try multiple it doesn't work.

```
=COUNTIFS(D10:D,TODAY()-1, J10:J, "<>cancelled"OR("<>rescheduled"OR("<>no show")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(D10:D,TODAY()-1, J10:J, "<>cancelled", J10:J, "<>rescheduled", J10:J, "<>no show")
```